# printing the pandas dataframe column following the string format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a code to generate the following output

```
x1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
x2 = [',', ',', ',', ',']
test_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
test_dataframe['id'] = x1
test_dataframe['sep'] = x2
print(test_dataframe[['id','sep']].to_string(index=False))


id sep
 A   ,
 B   ,
 C   ,
 D   ,
```

However, I would like to let the output of id column follows the following format

```
id  sep
 'A' ,
 'B' ,
 'C' ,
 'D' ,
```

How to achieve this kind of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is using `Series.map` + `str.format`

```
test_dataframe['id'] = test_dataframe['id'].map("'{0}'".format)
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(test_dataframe[['id2', 'sep']].to_string(index=False))

  id sep
 'A'   ,
 'B'   ,
 'C'   ,
 'D'   ,
```

Comment: may I know the meaning of {0} in the map function? Thanks.

Comment: @user785099 It's a placeholder that denotes the first positional argument passed to the `str.format` function. In this case, denotes each element of the column. Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp). I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the " ' " manually to your id column.

`df['id']= "'"+df ['id'] + "'"`

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to temporarily change the printing format as you want for `print`. Instead, you can add `'` to the value as follows:

```
x1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
x2 = [',', ',', ',', ',']
test_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
test_dataframe['id'] = x1
test_dataframe['sep'] = x2
test_dataframe['id2'] = test_dataframe['id'].apply(lambda x: "'" + x + "'")
print(test_dataframe[['id2', 'sep']].to_string(index=False))

# id sep
#'A'   ,
#'B'   ,
#'C'   ,
#'D'   ,
```